# Add to an array from matched key

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm not entirely sure how to title the question, but I'm trying to add to one Array from a second based on a matched string at index `0`. This is in a Google Apps Script web app, which is why it's all JavaScript-based rather than PHP.

```js
// Sent from client
Array1: ["A"]

// Stored on server
Array2: [["A", "June","15"], ["B","October","30"]]
```

I'd like to return the entire matching array based on the client-submitted form object.

I've tried:

```js
Array1 = Array1.filter(function(val) {
  return Array2.indexOf(val) !== -1;    // I thought this would return indices that matched
});
```

but I get an empty array returned instead of `["A","June","15"]`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used wrong `filter` function.You have to `filter` `Array2` based on `Array1` values.

```js
var Array1= ["A","B"]
var Array2=[["A", "June","15"], ["B","October","30"],["C","September","16"]]
var result = Array2.filter(function(val) {
  return Array1.indexOf(val[0])!=-1;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It works well for one, but if I want to expand `Array1` it finishes after the first result. If I want to expand `Array1`, how do I get it to loop through each key?

Comment: @BrianBennett, I edited my answer. Please take a look now.