# Gmail > IFTTT > Dropbox resurrection: select messages by label and dynamically assign keyword from spreadsheet column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Objective: to resume automatically downloading attachments from certain email addresses with pretty filenames.

I am looking at [Reddit user Esivni's wonderful workaround](https://www.reddit.com/r/ifttt/comments/b3zv1z/alternative_to_gmail_applet_using_sheetsapp/) after the death of Gmail triggers on IFTTT, and it occurred to me I should be able to extend it to dynamically choose keywords to include in the forwarding subject (ultimately the file name) for each sender from a corresponding spreadsheet column.

The Google Apps Script is set up to:
    A) select labels from a list in Google Sheets,
    B) change the original message's (thread's) label after processing
    C) forward all messages with those labels to trigger@applet.ifttt.com (or any address you choose), tagging the new subject line with the original label

An IFTTT applet then monitors emails sent to trigger@ for your chosen tag, discards the label, and downloads attachments to a specified path. Previously, when Gmail triggers still existed, I had one IFTTT applet for each email address I wanted to get attachments from, so that I could add a recognizable keyword to each file name (i.e. a short naming convention for vendor invoices) within the applet. It would be much more efficient to dynamically assign file names within the Apps script, and work with a single IFTTT applet.

I have added three columns to the sheet for:
    D) fromAddress
    E) shortName
    F) newSubject (which IFTTT will assign as file name - this column is mostly for debugging.)

What is the best way to loop through the first From address in each thread and assign its corresponding keyword?

I've tried pushing the getFrom() data into its own array, but that seems redundant. I'm including the entire function here in case there is a bracketing error that I'm missing.

```
function fwdSearch() {  
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:F6").getValues(); /* limiting the range for testing purposes */
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  for (i in data) {    
    var row = data[i];   
    var currentlblstr = row[0].toString(); /* Emails with label that we want to react to. */
    var newlblstr = row[1].toString(); /* Label we want to move the emails to once done. Otherwise we will hit app script execution limit quickly.*/
    var email = row[2].toString(); /* Email to forward to. */
    var fromaddr = row[3].toString(); /* From address */
    var shortname = row[4].toString();/* Name to append the subject to */
    var filename = row[5].toString; /* File name for first attachment */

    /* Make sure we are not reacting to null variables. */
    if ((currentlblstr !="") && (newlblstr !="") && (email != "") && (fromaddr != "")) {
      var currlbl = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(currentlblstr); /* Label object we are reacting to. */
      var newlbl = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(newlblstr); /* Label object we are moving emails to once done. */
      var threads = currlbl.getThreads(); /* alternative: var threads = GmailApp.search ("label:" + currlbl + "from:" + fromaddr);*/
      Logger.log("threads: "+threads)
    for (var x in threads) {         /* is this redudant? */
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
   {
     var messages = threads[x].getMessages()[0];}
     var mailAddress; // from Mathieu Passenaud's Gmail Auto Label function entryPoint()
        if(messages.getFrom().indexOf("<") != -1){  // if there is a < , we need to extract the mail from < and >
        mailAddress = messages.getFrom().substring(messages.getFrom().indexOf("<")+1, messages.getFrom().indexOf(">"));
        } else{
        // else, mail address is directly given
        mailAddress = messages.getFrom();                           
        }

      }}
        Logger.log("mailAddress: "+mailAddress);

   for (var i = 0; i < mailAddress.length; i++) {

     var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
     var lookupRangeValues = sheet.getRange(2,4,lr,1).getValues();

   var index = lookupRangeValues[i][0].indexOf(mailAddress[i]);

   Logger.log("lookupRangeValues: "+lookupRangeValues);
   Logger.log("index: "+index);}

    /* next step will be: GmailApp.sendEmail(email, name + messages[y].getSubject() + " #" + currentlblstr, messages[y].getBody())

        }
         Remove the label we react to,
         in it's place add a diff label. 
          threads[x].removeLabel(currlbl);
          threads[x].addLabel(newlbl) */
```

According to my logs I'm currently looping through the spreadsheet rows, not the threads as I expected (yes, I've tried threads[i]).getMessages()), and it's returning one random email address from the batch. Right now it's throwing "TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined." for `var index = lookupRangeValues[i][0].indexOf(mailAddress[i]);`. Despite the error, the lookup range values are returning correctly, and it returns indexes of something - I'm just not sure what. It's been a long time since I last used GAS or JS, so I appreciate any corrections. Thanks!

REVISION: This excerpt returns a filename (subject) for the fifth (last) item in the messages array, and places it in the correct cell. I used [this method][Add to an array from matched key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513775/add-to-an-array-from-matched-key), which looks like it should loop through all of the messages? Again, posting it to the sheet is for testing, if I could reference the object directly I know it would be more efficient.

```
function defineindex() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:F7").getValues();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  for (i in data) {    
    var row = data[i];   
    var currentlblstr = row[0].toString(); /* Emails with label that we want to react to. */
    var newlblstr = row[1].toString(); /* Label we want to move the emails to once done. Otherwise we will hit app script execution limit quickly.*/
    var email = row[2].toString(); /* Email to forward to. */
    var fromaddr = row[3].toString(); /* From address */
    var shortname = row[4].toString();/* Name to append the subject to */
    var filename = row[5].toString; /* File name for first attachment */
  } /* closed */

 if ((currentlblstr !="") && (newlblstr !="") && (email != "") && (fromaddr != "")) {
      /* if ((from != from))*/
      var currlbl = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(currentlblstr); /* Label object we are reacting to. */
      var newlbl = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(newlblstr); /* Label object we are moving emails to once done. */
      var threads = currlbl.getThreads();
      /*var threads = GmailApp.search ("label:" + currlbl + "from:" + fromname);*/
      Logger.log("threads: "+threads)
      for (var x in threads) {      
        /*var messages = threads[x].getMessages();*/

    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
   {
    var messages = threads[x].getMessages()[0];} /* to get messages one at a time */
    var emailArray = []  
    var mailAddress;
        if(messages.getFrom().indexOf("<") != -1){       // if there is a < , we need to extract the mail from < and >
        mailAddress = messages.getFrom().substring(messages.getFrom().indexOf("<")+1, messages.getFrom().indexOf(">"));
        } else{
        // else, mail address is directly given
        mailAddress = messages.getFrom();                           
        }
      emailArray.push(mailAddress);
        Logger.log("emailArray: "+emailArray)

     var keys = []
        keys.push(sheet.getRange("D2:E").getValues());
        Logger.log("keys: "+keys)

//var Array1= ["A","B"] (fromaddr) <<< for reference, from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513775/add-to-an-array-from-matched-key
//var Array2=[["A", "June","15"], ["B","October","30"],["C","September","16"]] (emailArray)
    for (var k = 0; k < emailArray.length; k++)
      var result = keys[k].filter(function(val) {
      return emailArray.indexOf(val[0])!=-1;
});
        Logger.log("result: "+result[0][1]) // first row in keys (fromAddr/shortName), second column (shortName)
        console.log("result: "+result);

//       if ( data[3][i] === emailArray ) {
   for (k in emailArray){
     filename = []
     filename.push(result[k][1] + " " + messages.getSubject() + " #" + currentlblstr);  }}}
  Logger.log("filename: "+filename + "& K: "+k) /* K returns only 0 */
     sheet.getRange(i-1, 6).setValue(filename[k]);  }
```

I'm considering using another function to temporarily label each message with its corresponding prefix to avoid looking it up in the script above. But is that really necessary? [Here's a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j40s9z-ZLxvRZ2yUZOwmz23id27I_V5PvpHaeFRsumk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I missed what you are trying to do.
This is what I understood:

1. You want to get the threads with an specific label
2. Send those threads to an email address specified in the sheet
3. Use the label as the subject for the new email
4. Attach the files from the original emails to the new ones <s>, changing its name.</s>

I did this code, but even if I haven't done the step 4 yet <s>(if you want to take a look, it will be done with [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source))</s>, I think it's pointing in the good direction:

```
function main() {  
  var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sprsheet.getActiveSheet();

  var data = {
    currentlblstr:sheet.getRange("A2:A6").getValues(),//In case you have more than A6, B6, etc, change the range to "A2:A", "B2:B", etc
    newlblstr:sheet.getRange("B2:B6").getValues(),
    email:sheet.getRange("C2:C6").getValues(),
    fromaddr:sheet.getRange("D2:D6").getValues(), //Since you are using appscript, the mails will be sent from the google user you are logged in
    shortname:sheet.getRange("E2:E6").getValues(), //I'm not sure what the shortname is for
    filename:sheet.getRange("F2:F6").getValues()
  };


  if (!CheckNulls(data)){
    for (var i in data.currentlblstr){
      try {
          var threads = findThreads(data.currentlblstr[i]), data.email[i]);

          var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];

          var body = message.getBody();
          var attachment = message.getAttachments();
          var label = message.getLabels()[0].getName();
          var fileName = attachment[0].getName();

          threads[0].getMessages()[0].forward(data.email[i], {
                                      subject: data.shortname[i] + " " + label,
                                      attachments: fileName});

          //Remove the label from the current thread
          var rem_label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label);
          var add_label = data.newlblstr[i];
          rem_label.removeFromThread(threads[0]);

    } catch (e) {
           Logger.log("No emails found" + e);
  }
      }   
    }

function CheckNulls(data){ // Returns true if there is any empty cell
  for (var key in data){

    for (var i in data[key]){

      if(!data[key][i][0]){
        return true;
      } 
    }
  }
}

function findThreads(labels, from){
   var threads = GmailApp.search("label:"+ labels + " from:" + from); 
   return threads; //Returns an object GmailThread [1] 

}
```

Right now it executes the steps 1 to 3 correctly. I will finish this later, but I hope it's helpful for now.

More information about GMailThreads: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#

Comment: Thank you for reply! Mine works for those steps as well, however where I get hung up is _dynamically setting the subject from a list of keywords_ (shortName) that correspond to the sender of the attachment. So the variable fromAddr (parsed by mailAddress later in the script) is not mine, but the original sender. Ex.: an email might have a subject "Invoice XXXX", from "ar@thiscompany.com", and I want the subject of the forwarded message to begin with with "COMP". A different function periodically updates a list of senders, and I manually assign each address a shortName for filing.

Comment: Hi, could you edit your post and add the code you did? So I understand you want the subject to begin with "COMP", which is a shortname for "thiscompany" you defined previously. Then "Invoice XXXX" would be the rest of the subject, which is the name of the file attached to the emails. I guess I got this right. I edited my original answer.

Comment: Not quite, but thanks for following up. I edited my question for clarity before my previous reply, but the code didn't change. I don't see in your solution where the keyword is chosen based on the sender of each email. That is the only part I'm having trouble with. Does that make sense? I am curious to know why you chose to change the rest of the code, though, is it really more efficient that way?

Comment: Hi, the shortname is related to the sender as the loop takes one row of the table at a time, so when `i = 1` then it takes `sender1`, `shortname1`, etc. Supposing you created the keyword manually before executing the script. Also, the thing I changed is `forward` instead of `sendmail`. It's still using GmailApp, but it's more "correct" since we are forwarding and not sending new emails. Can you post an example of the table you use, and an example of one subject?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I can tell your script loops through the data, but not the threads. Essentially, I need to say: _"for each thread with label x, if the sender of the first message (there is generally only one message, but we have to choose one to retrieve anyway) matches a spreadsheet row, return column 5 of that row"_ (but efficiently.) That's why I was trying to use indexOf(). [Here's a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j40s9z-ZLxvRZ2yUZOwmz23id27I_V5PvpHaeFRsumk/edit?usp=sharing) so it's easier to see what I mean.

Comment: Ok! Sorry for misunderstanding. How about adding `from` in the search query and using the emails from the table? It would avoid the process of comparing each email found with the table and if success it will return the `shortName` of the same index. I updated my code.

Comment: I still don't see how that would work. If you're still interested, feel free to take a look at my updated code!